# How to handle getting new data even?

Tags: vue.js

I have got Vue-JS app. After use click variable `rasters_previews_list` get new data. I would like to generate list with them. I can't understand which directive I should use to handle this even.

Here is my code:

```
var userContent = Vue.extend({
      template: `

    <div class="LayersMenuSectionContent" v-if="rasters_previews_list.length">

           <ul v-for="img in rasters_previews_list">
             <li>{{img.id}}</li> // generate list here
           <ul>
     </div>

          `,
        data: function ()  {
          return {

            rasters_previews_list: [] // when come new data I should generate li with then

          }

          },

          ready: function()
          { 

          },

          methods: 
          { 

          }

        });
```

Should I use `v-on` or `v-if`?

Answer (score 1):

When `rasters_previews_list` is changed, list is autorendered in `v-for`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div class="LayersMenuSectionContent" v-show="rasters_previews_list.length">
    <ul v-for="img in rasters_previews_list">
      <li>{{img.id}}</li>
    <ul>
  </div>
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
          `,
  data: function ()  {
    return {
      rasters_previews_list: [] // when come new data I should generate li with then
    }
  },
  ready: function(){ },
  methods: { 
    add(){
      this.rasters_previews_list.push({id: 'hello'},{id: 'world'});
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Extra: You must use `v-show` instead of `v-if` for this case